# SKlearn LogisticRegression bad input shape ERROR

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

How do I get rid of this error

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.read_csv("train.csv")

clean = {"Sex": {"male":1, "female":0}} 
df.replace(clean, inplace = True)
df["label"] = df['Survived']
df =  df.drop(["Name","Ticket","Cabin","Embarked","Fare","Parch","Survived"],  axis = 1)
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how="any")

X = df.drop(["label"],axis = 1).values
y = df["label"].values

X_train , y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.7)

log_reg  = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Accuracy on test subset: (:.3f)".format(log_reg.score(X_train, y_train)))

ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\17\kaggle'\logistic.py", line 20, in <module>
    log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 1216, in fit
    order="C")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 547, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 583, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (500, 5)
```

Comment: Can you show us what `X.shape` and `y.shape` are after you use `.values` on the pandas DataFrame? It *looks* like they should have the correct shape and type (a 2D and 1D numpy.array, respectively) and the only reason I can think it would be different is if the DataFrame is empty (zero rows survive the dropna(), for example.)

Comment: X.shape gives (714, 5)   and y.shape gives (714,).

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to this:

```
X_train , y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.7)
```

This is not what the `train_test_split` returns.

The actual usage should be:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.7)
```

`train_test_split` will return the splitted arrays in order of supplied data. So X will be split into `X_train, X_test` and returned first, then y will be returned as `y_train y_test`.
Hope this helps.